# Why is delaying the task not executing it fully or blocking the UI?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

```
private async Task<string> httpClient(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();

    hc.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

    //Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); using this one, it blocks the UI thread
    //await Task.Delay(5000); using this one, it doesn't execute the task after delay

    if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return null;
    }

    HttpResponseMessage response = await hc.GetAsync(new Uri("http://google.com/"));

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return responseData;
}
```

This is my async task and I have an issue trying to use delay inside of it. I have tried two methods and both seem to cause an issue with the task. Tried researching but couldn't find a way to fix my issue. Any help is appreciated

Other part of the code:

```
private async void Test()
{
    string response = await httpClient(token);
    Console.WriteLine("response: " + response);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task t = new Task(Test);
    t.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("task started");
    t.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("task finished");
}
```

Comment: `Task.Delay(5000).Wait();` - yes, that would block the UI thread (if it ever completes); don't do that; as for `await Task.Delay(5000);` - that *looks* like it should work - what actually happens?

Comment: Is there a timeout on the cancellation token?

Comment: @MarcGravell I added the other part of the code. What happens is when I click button1, it prints out "task started" and "task finished" immediately.

Comment: Don't create a new HttpClient for each request, keep one object for all of them (reference here https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). Also, you should pass cancelToken to the methods that you await, pass it to GetAsync.

Comment: @Nkosi The cancellation token is an event on button2, and no delay only .Cancel() is called, but I never press that button while waiting for button1's click event.

Comment: @gafs and that's why we don't use `async void` :)

Comment: You are reading a stream asynchronously.  Async doesn't know when the end of the data is found so it just continues to look for more data.  Nothing will happen unless the server closes the connection.  The Http know when the response ends duo to the tags in the message.  But the ReadAsStringAsync() does not know anything about the tags and continues to look for more data.

Comment: @gafs refactor the code to be async all the way. avoid async void unless event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
private async void Test()
{
    string response = await httpClient(token);
    Console.WriteLine("response: " + response);
}
```

As soon as you've made something `async void` you've completely removed any ability to track status. Your `new Task(Test);` is using `new Task(Action)`, which will report completion as soon as the code first returns to the caller - i.e. at the first non-complete `await` (in your case: the `Task.Delay`). To do what you want, you should really be using the `Task.Run(Func<Task>)` API (or avoiding `Task.Run` / `Task.Start` completely, relying on the async plumbing itself), with a `private async Task Test()` method.

Your event handler could then be:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("about to start task");
    var t = Task.Run(Test);
    Console.WriteLine("task started");
    await t;
    Console.WriteLine("task finished");
}
```

or to avoid the extra thread (as noted by Nkosi):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("about to start task");
    var t = Test();
    Console.WriteLine("task started");
    await t;
    Console.WriteLine("task finished");
}
```

Comment: `Task.Run` could be removed all together and just `await Test()`

Comment: @Nkosi yes, that's true too

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got one question. If I were to change the void to `Task<string>` and `return response`, how would I call the task from my button? I used `Task t = new Task(() => Test());` and got a `warning` saying `Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.`. Is that something to worry about?

Comment: @gafs `var response = await Test()` provided `private Task<string> Test() { ... return response;}`

Comment: @gafs you didn't `await t;`, then... note that I've only included the `t` local to allow you to log between starting and completion - a more idiomatic usage would be simply: `await Test();`. If you change it to be a `Task<string>`, then it would be `var result = await Test();`

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate all the help.